# Float is causing problems in my CSS design

Tags: html, css

When I am using `float:left;` in `.box1` and `float:none;` (or not use the float element) in `.box2` the overall layout/design of `.box2` moves behind the box1 but all the text content of box2 left behind at its previous place. So please explain why and how this is happening and provide solution using float only if possible. Please consider that I am a beginner before answering the question.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Float</title>
    <!-- Float just flows the element to left or right -->
    <style>
        *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .container{
            background-color: aqua;
            height: 70vh;
            width: 80vw;
            text-align: center;
            
        }
        .box1{
            background-color: red;
            border: 3px solid black;
            height: 25vh;
            width: 20vw;
            font-size: 3vh;
            float: left;
        }
        .box2{
            background-color: rgb(248, 11, 177);
            border: 3px solid black;
            height: 25vh;
            font-size: 3vh;
            width: 20vw;
            /* float: right; */
        }
        .box3{
            background-color: rgb(7, 206, 67);
            border: 3px solid black;
            height: 25vh;
            width: 20vw;
            font-size: 3vh;
            float: right;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box1">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio sapiente pariatur quidem laudantium</div>
        <div class="box2">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, sed! Cumque saepe dolore.</div>
        <div class="box3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In optio est accusamus?
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve would be good. Also maybe you could use css flex blox instead of messing around with floats, etc?

Answer (score 0):

According [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float), `float` only works with text or inline elements. Therefore, you need to make floated elements inline (`display: inline`, `display: inline-block`, `display: inline-flex`, etc.). Example below:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 70vh;
  width: 80vw;
  text-align: center;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: red;
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 25vh;
  width: 20vw;
  font-size: 3vh;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: rgb(248, 11, 177);
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 25vh;
  font-size: 3vh;
  width: 20vw;
  display: inline-block;
  /* float: right; */
}

.box3 {
  background-color: rgb(7, 206, 67);
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 25vh;
  width: 20vw;
  font-size: 3vh;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio sapiente pariatur quidem laudantium</div>
  <div class="box2">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, sed! Cumque saepe dolore.</div>
  <div class="box3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In optio est accusamus?
  </div>
</div>
```